SedEngine. Invalid buffer, size 2048, Error when suing MLKIT SoundDetector on some devices
I am using the MLKIT sample Text Apk downloaded from Demo APK Download Package (Text Module)
When I run the app and select voice recognition module in it. modules list screenshot
After allowing the mic access , I get the constant error as follows in the logcat
SedEngine             E  Invalid buffer, size 2048
What can be causing this and how to solve it .
Tried to build codes of another repos on github using hms-ml on the same device and these also give the same error
